# Spread operator in React Native causes 'Unexpected token' error with mocha

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, ecmascript-6, react-native, babeljs

I'm starting a React Native project, and I'd like to use ECMAScript 2015 for my code, and mocha for my unit tests. I've installed `babel-register`, `babel-preset-es2015`, and `babel-preset-stage-2`, and added this to my project's `package.json` file:

```
"babel": {
    "presets": ["es2015", "stage-2"]
}
```

But when I run `mocha --compilers js:babel-register` and try to test a module that imports a React Native API...

```
import React from 'react-native';

let {Dimensions} = React;
```

...I get an error about the spread operator used by React:

```
node_modules/react-native/Libraries/react-native/react-native.js:107
...require('React'),
^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
```

Is this a babel bug—shouldn't the stage-2 preset add support for the spread operator? Or am I missing something else?

Comment: I just don't understand your use of spread operator here. Why are you using it here?

Comment: I'm not using the spread operator. React Native is using it, and I'm importing React Native in one of my modules.

Comment: If you look at the package.json in react-native (https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/package.json), you will see that it imports around 30 babel-related packages. Without adding all of them, you will probably continue to experience these kinds of hickups with missing packages.

Comment: Any progress with this? I get the same error with a simple webpack script to compile and load a tiny typescript file. My loader does not invoke babel: `{ test: /\.tsx?$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'ts' }`

Answer (score 2):

I just started seeing this too. Seems like a bug. AFAIK babel doesn't compile files under node_modules because they should always be precompiled.

Also this is a pretty recent addition

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/f9b744d50137de25357994fe2e829f98104e2242

Comment: I get the same error with a simple webpack script to compile and load a tiny typescript file. My loader does not invoke babel: `{ test: /\.tsx?$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'ts' }` The loader that this line invokes is `ts-loader`